# Generating passbook pass signature file in C#

Tags: c#, passbook

1. App is about generating passes (Passbook App in Iphone) through C#.
2. I have downloaded Pass certificate and AppleWWDRCA certificate.
3. To generate pass I am able to generate pass.json and manifest.json.
4. But when I generate a PKCS 7 detached signature file using signing certificates and manifest.json it is not getting recognized by Passbook app in iphone.
5. I generated detached signature file using openssl in MAC and that is working fine and getting installed in Passbook.
6. I have downloaded pass certificate and AppleWWDRCA certificate
7. Can anyone help me in step by step procedure of creating signature file in c# and methods to be used

I have stored both the certificates in local folder not in windows local store. I have tried in windows local store before but it was not working.

below is the method used for signature,

```
 X509Certificate2 card = GetCertificate(); //Fetches the pass certificate   
X509Certificate2 appleCA = GetAppleCertificate();  //Fetches the AppleWWDRCA certificate    
    byte[] manifestbytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(manifest);
            ContentInfo contentinfo = new ContentInfo(manifestbytes);
            SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(contentinfo, true);
            var signer = new CmsSigner(SubjectIdentifierType.IssuerAndSerialNumber,card);
            signer.Certificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(appleCA));
            signer.IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.WholeChain;
            signer.SignedAttributes.Add(new Pkcs9SigningTime());
            signedCms.ComputeSignature(signer);
            signatureFile = signedCms.Encode();
            return signatureFile;
```

Answer (score 5):

I have created an open source C# library for generating these passes.

https://github.com/tomasmcguinness/dotnet-passbook

This is the code I use perform the signing of the files (it uses BouncyCastle)

```
// Load your pass type identifier certificate
X509Certificate2 card = GetCertificate(request);

Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate cert = DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(card);
Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.AsymmetricKeyParameter privateKey = DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair(card.PrivateKey).Private;

// Load the Apple certificate
X509Certificate2 appleCA = GetAppleCertificate(request);
X509.X509Certificate appleCert = DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(appleCA);


ArrayList intermediateCerts = new ArrayList();

intermediateCerts.Add(appleCert);
intermediateCerts.Add(cert);

Org.BouncyCastle.X509.Store.X509CollectionStoreParameters PP = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.Store.X509CollectionStoreParameters(intermediateCerts);
Org.BouncyCastle.X509.Store.IX509Store st1 = Org.BouncyCastle.X509.Store.X509StoreFactory.Create("CERTIFICATE/COLLECTION", PP);

CmsSignedDataGenerator generator = new CmsSignedDataGenerator();

generator.AddSigner(privateKey, cert, CmsSignedDataGenerator.DigestSha1);
generator.AddCertificates(st1);

CmsProcessable content = new CmsProcessableByteArray(manifestFile);
CmsSignedData signedData = generator.Generate(content, false);

signatureFile = signedData.GetEncoded();
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have created pass and deployed to azure, and was trying to download the same from safari browser but it says that it shows me the message that the resource could not found or moved to another location